# Add tags to the user profile?

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page, user-card

It would be nice to be able to add a limited amount (like 4?) of tags to the user profile to show other what areas you are most fluent/interrested in. Like If I'm working only with vb.net and sql I could Add [vb.net] and [sql] to the profile.

Those tags should then be possible to see as a tooltip or revealing infobox when hovering the mouse over the userinfo for a question or answer (or comment). It give good information about the questioner/answerer that can be considered when evaluate the answer given, or just to see what language the questioner prefer to have the examples in.

And it makes us a little bit more glued together when we know each others personal language/tools of choice.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is already possible; just go to any user profile page and look for the top tags -- those are the tags the user provided the most questions and answers.

Comment: I think Its two different things. If I for example look at your top tags on this site  I see that you have "Feature Request", "Discussion" and "bug" as your top tags. But thats not "who you are" or what you love to do?  Sure, it shows what you are doing on the site, but not what programmnig language you prefer working in, what technologies you like to work with and so on. I for example like to program against hardware, but havent answered a single software2hardware-question yet so no one will know before I using that tag in Q/A (or writing it in the profile).

Comment: And it would be neat to be able to search for users based on their own tags.

Comment: Not really relevant, request here is to see them in the user card.

Answer (score 2):

You can always state your preferences in the `about me` part of your profile.

Comment: Yes, I can. but: 1) that will not give me a quick overview of users particiating in a Q/A just with an mouse hover.  2) Tags are good for more, categorizing, searching, presentation, and so on. 3) Five tags says more than 500 words. ;)

Comment: @Stefan that's true. But using actual tags could be abused, while the current system of counting your tagged Q&As seems more reliable. And usually these tags (with the exception of mods, there I agree with your comment to Jeff) should state the very same. However, the hover-idea for the top5 tags wouldn't be such a bad idea...

Comment: if you look at my top tags on stackoverflow it seems like im a C# programmer, but Im not. Im a VB.Net-programmer, just that I can answer C#-questions too and there are more C#-questions to answer than VB.net. So it's not only mods that get it "wrong". But I would gladly accept the "top 5 tags" instead if my idea do'nt seems good enough. Better that than nothing. ;)